# About a widget to get coordinates in Web API?

Tags: coordinates, arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

I need to know if there is a widget that lets me draw a geometric figure in the map, and get the coordinates of the selected area.

Any similar widget is welcome.

Comment: how about Coordinate widget to display the coordinates dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

**Widget Draw** is the widget that works for me. It gives the coordinates, when you finish to draw a polygon, circle, rectangle, etc.